# Reading from a .CSV file that contains multiple values in one column Python

Tags: python, api

I am using python version 3.7.7 and need to read through an uploaded .csv file to send across an API call. The problem is that I have multiple values separated by a semi-column in one column; for which I have to split and populate an array object within the API.

I am reading each row with the reader object like this:

For row in reader:

Build my list of each record:

**

```
fileList = {"imageUrl": row["Urls'],
            "firstName": row["FirstName"],
            "categories": [
                             {
                               "id": row['Cate']
                             }
                          ]
```

**
The categories contain the array object that holds multiples. The values supplied on the .csv for this column is set up as such: 58748; 369865; 42755

I have tried using a for loop above the categories section in order to create more than one object within the array while splitting them out by the delimiter '; '.

```
**

for i in txt.split("; "):     
         d = i
          "categories": [
                          {
                           "id": d
                          }
                         ]
```

**

Comment: Could you include an example of your desired final value/result for `fileList`?

Comment: The output should look like: "categories": [ {"id":58748}, {"id":369865},{"id":42755} ]

Answer (score 0):

```py
fileList = [{"imageUrl":   row["Urls"],
             "firstName":  row["FirstName"],
             "categories": [{"id":val} for val in row['Cate'].split("; ")]
            } for row in reader]
```